# How to find the smallest $N$ in tolerance questions in sequences and series?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Question : Let the GP be $1,\left (\frac{-2}{3}\right), {\left (\frac{-2}{3}\right)}^2,{\left (\frac{-2}{3}\right)}^3, ... $

Choose a numerical tolerance $\epsilon=0.0005$. Determine the smallest integer $N$ such that $|S - s_n| < 0.0005$ whenever $n>N$. Here, $S$ is the sum of infinite terms of this GP which is $\frac{1}{1-r}$ and $s_n$ is the sum of the terms of this GP up to $n$ which is $\frac{1-r^{n+1}}{1-r}$

**My approach:**

$S - s_n = \frac{r^{n+1}}{1-r} = \frac{3}{5}{\left (\frac{-2}{3}\right)}^{n+1}$

Now, 
$$|S - s_n| < 0.0005$$
$$\frac{3}{5}{\left (\frac{-2}{3}\right)}^{n+1} < 0.0005$$ and
$$\frac{3}{5}{\left (\frac{-2}{3}\right)}^{n+1} > - 0.0005$$

Now, how do we calculate those values of $n$ from these inequalities which will make the absolute value equation in the question true?

Answer (score 1):

A mistake was made:

$$|S-s_n|=\left|\frac34\left(\frac{-2}{3}\right)^{n+1}\right|\neq \frac34\left(\frac{-2}{3}\right)^{n+1}$$

In fact, you have $$|S-s_n|=\left|\frac34\left(\frac{-2}{3}\right)^{n+1}\right|= \frac34\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{n+1}$$

so you need to find the $n$ at which $$\frac34\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{n+1}<0.0005.$$

In order to find this $n$, consider the following:

- All exponential functions are monotone.
- If $0<a<1$, then $a^x$ is a decreasing function.
- For every $B>0$, there exists a unique solution to the equation $a^x=B$ (think about logarithms).
- If $0<a<1$, and $a^{x_0}=B$, then $a^{x}<B$ for all $x>x_0$. Also, if $x<x_0$, then $a^x>B$.